# Paypal API calls to get Order Details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I need your suggestion regarding which Paypal API to use for my following requirement:

I am developing a application for Order management & Shipping in which I need to fetch order details like Billing & Shipping Address information + Item/product details + Billing amount etc on behalf of various merchants.

I will be fetching the data in two ways: 
1. Initial onetime fetch to get all orders till date. 
2. Regular fetch to get new orders.

Can you please suggest which API calls will get me the required data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I have found a solution for this through Paypal forum & API docs. Wanted to add the solution here so that it is helpful to other stackoverflow folks.

To lookup what transactions took place I can use the [TransactionSearch API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-nvp), say with the date range.
To get details of a particular transaction I can use [GetTransactionDetails API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp).

Since I have to do it on behalf of various merchants, I can use the Paypal Permissions API to allow merchants to authenticate me for making API calls on there behalf.